# Linear map with $f^k(v)=0$ for every $v\in V$ implies $\dim\ker f\geq n/k$ for finite dimensional vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\im}{\textrm{im}}$
Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and $f\colon V\to V$ a linear map with $f^k(v)=0$ for every $v\in V$. Show that $\dim\ker f\geq n/k$.

I was able to prove the claim for $k=2$. I showed that $\im f\subseteq \ker\ f$ and using the rank-nullity theorem we can conclude,

$$−n=−\dim\ker f−\dim\im\ f\geq−\dim\ker f−\dim\ker f=−2\dim\ker f$$
From that follows $\dim\ker f\geq n/2$.

I have a hard time to apply my approach to the general case for $k$. I have the suspicion that the rank-nullity theorem has to be applied in this case, too, but I don't see how. Any hint that can guide me into a direction to attack this case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `\dim` and `\ker` to get $\dim$ and $\ker$, instead of $dim$ and $ker$.

Comment: $\newcommand{im}{\textrm{im}}$It might help to note that we have $\ker f^i\subseteq\ker f^{i+1}$; $\im f^i\supseteq\im f^{i+1}$ for all $1\leq i\lt k$ and $\im f^{k-1}\subseteq\ker f^k$

Comment: Thank you, I will use the commands as you said, azif00.

Comment: Prasun Biswas, thank you very much for your contribution. Very helpful comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\text{img}(f^k) = 0$ so I think of $f^n$ as mapping $V$ to smaller and smaller (in dimension) subspaces as $n$ increases. Let's formalize this a bit, this process starts at $V_0 = V$ and then define $V_n = \text{img}(f^n)$. Then $f$ restricts to surjective maps $f_n : V_n \to V_{n+1}$ (check this). So we have the sequence of surjective maps:

$$V = V_0 \overset{f_0}{\to} V_1 \overset{f_1}{\to} ... V_{k-1} \overset{f_{k-1}}{\to} V_k = 0$$

Then I think the following plan will let you to prove the result:

1. Note the relation between $f^k$ to the composite of the maps above. Use this to express $\dim\ker(f^k)$ in terms of $\dim\ker(f_0), ..., \dim\ker(f_{k-1})$.
2. What can be said of $\dim\ker(f_n)$ in terms of $\dim\ker(f)$? Keep in mind the desired inequality and that $\dim\ker(f^k) = n$.

Comment: Thank you very much! With your help I was able to prove it.